# Как в строке найти слово или слово сочетание? Доработать или изменить уже имеющийся код

Tags: php

Написал такой код, он как бы работает но не совсем так как нужно.

```html
$search = "как твои дела";
$text = "привет, как твои дела? давай созвонимся.";
$pos1 = stripos($text, $search);

if ($pos1 !== false) {

    echo 'Найден '.$search;

}
```

Код выше отлично ищет в строке слово "как твои дела" но если искать например слово "да" то он его найдет в "давай" но само искомое слово "да" это как бы отдельное слово а он его находит как две буквы в тексте.

Как написать так чтобы искались именно слова или слово сочетания?

Comment: В тексте заменить знаки пунктуации пробелами. В поисковой строке добавить пробелы по краям фразы.

Comment: по-моему, без регулярных выражений не обойтись. Что-то вроде '\b$search\b'. А код находит всё правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Из комментария:**

> В тексте заменить знаки пунктуации пробелами. В поисковой строке
>   добавить пробелы по краям фразы. – [MAX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/297727/max)

**Реализация:**

```
$search = "как твои дела";
$text = "привет, как твои дела? давай созвонимся.";

$text = ' ' . preg_replace("#[[:punct:]]#", ' ', $text) . ' ';

if (stripos($text, ' ' . $search . ' ') !== FALSE) {
    echo 'Найден '.$search;
}
```

---

**Из комментария:**

> по-моему, без регулярных выражений не обойтись. Что-то вроде
>   '\b$search\b'. А код находит всё правильно. – [Adokenai](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/296878/adokenai)

**Реализация:**

```
$search = "как твои дела";
$text = "привет, как твои дела? давай созвонимся.";

$pattern = '#\b'.$search.'\b#isu';

if (preg_match($pattern, $text)) {
    echo 'Найден';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, с регулярным выражением отлично, и код простой и работает хорош.